# Why does y change to $y+\mathrm{d}y$ here?

Tags: calculus

So I've been trying to study calculus from Calculus Made Easy by Silvanus P. Thompson and Martin Gardener, and there's a point where I'm stuck.

As it says in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC9Bx.jpg)

$$y=x^{2}$$

So when $x$ is changed to $x+\mathrm{d}x$, shouldn't the above equation change to
$$y = (x + \mathrm{d}x)^{2}$$

But instead it's given as
$$y+\mathrm{d}y = (x+\mathrm{d}x)^{2}$$

Can someone please help me understand why $y$ changes to $y+\mathrm{d}y$ ?
I'm really confused by this.

Comment: There are two points on the parabola. The first is $(x,y)$ and the second is $(x + \Delta x, y + \Delta y)$.

Comment: If $x$ changes, why wouldn't $y$ change too? After all they are related by the equation given.

Comment: As $x$ changes by a small amount, so does $y$ as it depends on $x$

Comment: The complete original text of Thompson's book (without Martin Gardner's notes) is available from Project Gutenberg: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/33283/33283-pdf.pdf. The passage in question here is on page 28 of that PDF file.

Answer (score 2):

let's say $y = f(x),\,f(x)=x^2$. Then $f(x+dx) = (x+dx)^2$. You can't say now that $y=(x+dx)^2$ as $y=f(x)$, not $f(x+dx)$. That's why you consider an increment of $y$ and write $y+dy = f(x+dx)$.

Answer (score 2):

When $x$ is changed to $x + \Delta x$, then $y$ becomes $y + \Delta y$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We're looking at all the solutions $(x, y)$ of the equation $y = x^2$. In particular, we're looking at two solutions that are very very close together, because we want to determine the slope of the curve of all solutions at that point.

So suppose we have two solutions $y = x^2$ and $y' = x'^2$. that are very close together. We call the difference between them $dx := x'-x$ and $dy = y'-y$. Rewriting $y' = x'^2$ in terms of $x, y, dx, dy$, we get $y+dy = (x+dx)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Points $(a,b)$ on the curve satisfy $b=a^2$. So since $(x,y)$ is on the curve, we have $y=x^2$.

If you move *along the curve* a little bit, you move to the point $(x+dx,y+dy)$. So you have that $$\underbrace{y+dy}_{\textrm{2nd coord}} = (\underbrace{x+dx}_{\textrm{1st coord}})^2$$ The "little bit" of movement is $(dx,dy)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a change.

It's a so called "infinitesimal increment".

Basically, you increment your quantity $y$ of a small infinitesimal amount called $\text{d}y$

It is like to say you have a given quantity $y$, and you want to increase it by a small bit. You call this small bit as $\text{d}y$ and you're done.

Then of course, since $x$ is related to $y$, changing $y$ means to change $x$ too.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=x^2$ then $(y+\delta y)=(x+\delta x)^2$:

[image: differential of y=x^2]

Comment: Why are $x$ and $y$ not measured from where the axes cross?